# Rack Bug Installation issue. Server does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling

I just installed the Rack-Bug and created the middleware file that it needs in the config folder. But I am unable to start my server.
Im using Rails 2.3.4 with Ruby 1.8.7.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in     `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant IPAddr (NameError)
```

from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in`const_missing'
 from /home/xxxxx/xxxx/trunk/config/initializers/middleware.rb:6

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The solution is to put the following line at the top of your environment.rb (requirement of a ruby core class: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IPAddr.html):

require 'ipaddr'